# How can I connect my web server application with salesforce organizations, using OAuth2.0?

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

I have a web application made in .NET and I need to connect it with several Salesforce accounts to access data in Salesforce with OAuth2.0. How can I do it?

I have seen this document: https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm

and I need a client_id (Consumer key from the remote access application definition) to obtain Access Authorization. But as I want is to connect my application with salesforce organizations of my clients, on which I have no access credentials, how do I get the customer_id?

On the other hand I have seen applications that connect to salesforce redirected to this page to request permission:

"login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fsetup%2Fsecur%2FRemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp%3Fsource%3DXXXX&sdtd=1"

But I don't know what is the "source" param.

One of the applications I've seen that connects to salesforce and uses the authorization process is "zapier.com".

I made a zapier connecting to my development org and within "Connected Apps OAuth Usage", in mi org, Setup --> Administration Setup --> Manage Apps, I can see the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Pjr.jpg

Connected App: Zapier
User Count: 1

From this moment zapier can access the data from my salesforce organization via API.

This is exactly what I want to achieve.

I'm a little lost. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a Connected App ID in the customer org - just in your own DE org (see [this answer for a little more detail](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/14021/67)). So, create a Connected App in your DE org ([but see this note!](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/9983/67)), implement your app to use the web server flow (see [this article](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com) for much more detail), and users will be able to use your app. You can easily test by creating a second DE org and trying to use your app from there.